# Convert my Powershell script into an c# Windows Form

Tags: c#, powershell

Hello I am trying to "convert" my Powershell script into a Windows form so it is looking nice and not on the command line.

My Powershell script:

```
# Food selector for the week!
#random Stuff mixed for every day.

Enum RandomFood
{#Add Food here:
Pizza
Quesedias
Lasagne
}

Enum Meat
{#Add Food here:
Steak
Beaf
Chicken
Cordonbleu
}

function Food {

Clear-Host
  $Foods =  [Enum]::GetValues([RandomFood]) | Get-Random -Count 6
  $Foods += [Enum]::GetValues([Meat]) | Get-Random -Count 1

$foodsOfWeek = $Foods | Get-Random -Count 7
Write-Host `n "Here is you'r List of Meals for this week :D" `n
foreach ($day in [Enum]::GetValues([DayOfWeek])) {
    ([string]$day).Substring(0, 3) + ': ' + $foodsOfWeek[[DayOfWeek]::$day]
}
}
```

The problem is i am very new to C# and I am struggling on following points:

- The array with the meals in it (where do I create it? can I just use Enum again?)
- How can I get 7 random items out of the two arrays?
- How do I then output the meals to the text box in the form?

I do have a simple textbox (`textbox1`), and a button that should then generate all this (`button1`)

This is what I came up with in vb:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FoodSceduleGenerator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] arr1 = {"Pizza", "Quesedias","Lasagne"};
            textBox1.Text = arr1;


        }
```

But it did not work and I don't get it... I've spent 2 hours googling my way through but can't really get any further.

I am trying to output the entire array first so I can continue then.

Thanks for any help/tips to continue

Comment: Where is you `function Food`?

Comment: what do you mean? @SeM

Comment: Inside you PowerShell script you have `function Food`, where is you realization of it in c#?

Comment: i planned to do this in the button? doesen't this work like this like when i press the button it executes the code in it so i will put the function in there.

Comment: Why not build the windows form in PowerShell and hook it up to your code you already have?

Comment: Well if that would work i verry wellcome it! As long as it gets the output on the windows form!  Can you maybe explain me how that would work?